# Why does Casting this string as a decimal fail?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, cast

Why does casting this result of `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` to a DECIMAL fail?

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('Cost (-$14.18)', '(?<=Cost [(]-[$])[0-9.]+') AS _extracted,
    CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Cost (-$14.18)', '(?<=Cost [(]-[$])[0-9.]+') AS DECIMAL(8,2)) AS cost_1,
    CAST((SELECT _extracted) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) AS cost_2,
    CAST((SELECT _extracted) * 1 AS DECIMAL(8,2)) AS cost_3,
    CAST('14.18' AS DECIMAL(8,2)) AS cost_4;
```

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| _extracted | cost_1 | cost_2 | cost_3 | cost_4 |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 14.18      |  14.00 |  14.00 |  14.18 |  14.18 |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Casting a plain string as in `cost_4` seems to work. Multiplying the `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` result by `1` also appears to work.  But simply casting the result as I've done with `cost_1` and `cost_2` fails to produce the correct fixed point version of `_extracted`.

Oddly, in my application using the backreference as I've done for `cost_2` actually produces the correct result.  Was unable to reproduce elsewhere but thought it worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a long-standing issue with MySQL with people reporting [this very issue as a bug since 2011](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61691). I have found that the problem is almost completely dependent on the collation being used within the `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function.

For instance, if you cast the result of `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` as a `CHAR(100)`, your decimals remain intact:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Cost (-$14.18)', '[0-9.]+') AS CHAR(100)) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) AS result;

result
----- 
14.18
```

The result returned by `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` used a UTF-16 character set before MySQL 8.0.17. Versions after this supposedly use the same character set as configured by the client (See bug [#94203](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94203) reported by Rick James), but this does not appear accurate. My SQL client is configured to use UTF-8 everywhere. Running your initial query in my client produces the exact same results as you shared in the question.

However, if I `CONVERT( ... USING 'UTF8')`:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Cost (-$14.18)', '[0-9.]+') USING 'UTF8') AS DECIMAL(8,2)) AS result;

result
----- 
14.18
```

Surprise, surprise. A correct number.

Generally in this situation I do the very same thing that you did for `cost_3`; I multiply the returned value by 1, then cast it to the desired type. You can save a step by casting as `FLOAT`, but this sometimes has precision implications.

It is not a *great* answer, but it is one that can be used across multiple versions of MySQL.

Comment: That's about as thorough an explanation as I could have hoped for.  Presumably this also sheds light on why my backreference may have worked in some cases but still scratching my head about that one. And yes, I was encountering float precision issues which is exactly what led me to this point.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not `CAST`.  Use

```
FORMAT(expression, 2)  -- for displaying with 2 decimal places

ROUND(expression, 2)   -- for further computation
```

Comment: but, why does this fix the issue?

Comment: `FORMAT(x, 2)` returns float, not a fixed point number.  This leads to precision issues and results like `18.18 + 9.69 = 27.869999999999997` which is why I'm using `CAST()` to begin with.

Comment: @billynoah - I understood our Question to be talking about display, not storage or further computation.

Comment: In that case I've already accomplished the display aspect in step one where `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` is used to extract the number from the string. You can infer that decimal computation is required by the fact that I'm casting as a decimal.